# How can I create a symbol for the origin of a coordinate plane in Tikz?

Tags: fonts, symbols, calligraphy

[image]

This symbol appears at the origin of a coordinate plane in the Illustrative Mathematics curriculum, but I have no idea how to produce it using LaTeX or Tikz. Can you help me?

Comment: It's a calligraphic O, which you can obtain with the command ``\mathcal{O}``.
For further doubts about symbols, you can use [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), where you can draw the symbol and get its associated code. Alternatively, you can consult [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for a comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols.

Comment: Welcome to TeXSE. Also, for more symbols, please refer the file `symbols-a4.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired character can be typed using the *calligraphic* font, obtained through the `\mathcal` command in `math` mode, e.g., `$\mathcal{O}$` will give you the right typography,

[image]

A complete MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{O}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `amssymb` is irrelevant.

Comment: @campa Thank you Campa. I have put the amssymb because the user can search it on the list of all Symbols.

Comment: I see. However, especially for beginners I think it's better to load only packages necessary to the answer. Or at least add a comment that a package is a good idea but not strictly necessary.

Comment: @campa Thank you for your advice.